# How can I determine a number is irrational?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

I have a hypothesis about regular polygons, but in order to prove or disprove it I need a way to determine whether an expression is rational. Once I boil down my expression the only part that could be irrational is:

$$S_N = \cot \frac{\pi}{N} \text{ for } N\in ℕ_1 ∖ \left\{1, 2, 4\right\}$$

Is there at least one such $N$ for which $S_N$ is rational? Can it be proven that $S_N$ is never rational for any such $N$? How would I go about proving one or the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476/irrationality-of-trigonometric-functions

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensTheorem.html

Comment: I think (but this could be a dubious claim) that there is a theorem saying that $\sin(\pi n)$ and $\cos(\pi n)$ are *algebraic* numbers iff $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Comment: @Joseph: $\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$ and $\cos \frac{\pi}{n}$ (I assume this is what you meant) are always algebraic.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, though it is certainly related. Please see my comment to Ross Millikan's question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple, complete proof can be found in Olmsted, J. M. H., [Rational Values of Trigonometric Functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2304540), Amer. Math. Monthly 52 (1945), no. 9, 507–508.